# How to get Auto data using Custom date in Formula in Google Finance?

Tags: google-sheets

I have try to change date in Formula but showing error

[image]

Formal with Particular Date

```
ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TEXT(

 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), DATE(2021,2,1), "daily"), 

 {"yyyy mm", "@"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))
```

Formula With Date Change Showing Error

31/07/2023  31/01/2021

```
ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TEXT(

 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(A1), DATE(B1), "daily"), 

 {"yyyy mm", "@"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Finance doesn't recognise my date field and is returning an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268003/google-finance-doesnt-recognise-my-date-field-and-is-returning-an-error-message)

Comment: But while using SUM Formal to get Total Value is show Error (0)

Answer (score 0):

*You may try with not wrapping the cells within `DATE` function & also to make sure `[start_date]` is in A1 & `[end_date]` in B1*

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", A1, B1, "daily"),{"yyyy mm", "@"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))
```

[image]